# How can i check if an app exists on phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to check if an app exists on phone, I have searched on google but found nothing.
Can i get a list of installed apps on the phone with code??? Is there any other way to check this. Thanks all.

This is using WindowPhone 8.0 SDK

Okie, i can get list app by *current publisher*, but i can get list app by *other publisher*

```
            IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packagers = InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
            foreach (Windows.ApplicationModel.Package item in packagers)
            {
                //...
            }
```

**InstallationManager.FindPackages()** is not a public API

Comment: You can not get a list of installed apps. What are you trying to do? If you need to communicate with another app (your own or another), it can be done with uri schemes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if one of your own App is installed, [FindPackageForCurrentPublisher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher.aspx) is the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect what apps are installed on the phone via the publicly available Windows Phone 8 SDK. There must be a way to do this for "1st party" apps built by Microsoft, Nokia and the other OEMs. But as a 3rd party App developer it can't be done.

If you want to communicate with other apps I suggest you read up on URI schemes, there is a great list of documented URI schemes at the Nokia Developer Wiki: http://bit.ly/NokiaUriSchemes